# What gui library is used by sublime text editor?

Tags: python, user-interface, sublimetext

I've downloaded an editor of [sublimetext](http://www.sublimetext.com/) and I want to know what GUI library is used in there.

The filenames of files that are in the editor executables directory are:

```
bz2.pyd
Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest   
msvcp90.dll
msvcr90.dll                   
PackageSetup.py
PackageSetup.pyc              
pyexpat.pyd                   
python26.dll
python26.zip                  
select.pyd
sublimeplugin.py              
sublimeplugin.pyc
sublimetext.exe               
unicodedata.pyd
unins000.dat                  
unins000.exe
_ctypes.pyd                   
_elementtree.pyd
_hashlib.pyd                  
_socket.pyd
_ssl.pyd
```

Can I find the information from the file names?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Sublime Text 2 is mostly coded in C++ and uses a custom UI toolkit. Here is the author, Jon Skinner, explaining it: http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2822114.

> I keep meaning to write a blog post with some details on this, but as
>   with many things, I usually end up coding instead. Sublime Text 2 is
>   almost entirely C++ (with a smattering of Objective C for Cocoa and
>   Python for plugins). Coding is generally fairly straight forward: code
>   on one platform (mostly Linux at the moment, but I switch around
>   frequently), and then make sure it still compiles elsewhere. Sublime
>   Text 2 itself uses a custom UI toolkit. There are a lot of apps where
>   this may not make sense, but it's not such an unreasonable choice for
>   Sublime Text, where I always knew that a lot of the UI controls were
>   going to have to be custom no matter the toolkit (e.g., the text
>   control and tab controls). The UI toolkit sits on top of a cross
>   platform abstraction layer, which is more a union of platform
>   functionality rather than lowest common denominator.

Comment: Looks like that link no longer exists (404 Not Found)

Comment: From the author of Sublime 2: _"Sublime Text 2 itself uses a custom UI toolkit"_, we know it is a custom UI. And, based on the Sublime 2 libs and error messages, we can gather the _"custom UI"_ is based on GTK (at least in part).

Comment: Do you, guys, think that that _"custom UI"_ is hardware accelerated (OpenGL), or not?

Comment: Some post stated that he was using Direct2D on windows. Can't find the link now.

Comment: A few weeks ago I read on HackerNews (I think it was in the Sublime Merge release announcement) that the custom UI toolkit is based on [Skia](https://skia.org/).

Answer (score 29):

a little Googling suggested it is using the Sublime GUI, which judging by the Debian source package is written in C++.

then again, running `strings` on the Linux `sublime_text` binary shows the following shared libraries (equivalent of Windows DLLs) which might suggest gtk:

```
/lib/ld-linux.so.2
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0
libatk-1.0.so.0
libgio-2.0.so.0
libpangoft2-1.0.so.0
libpangocairo-1.0.so.0
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0
libcairo.so.2
libpng12.so.0
libpango-1.0.so.0
libfreetype.so.6
libfontconfig.so.1
libgobject-2.0.so.0
libgmodule-2.0.so.0
libgthread-2.0.so.0
librt.so.1
libglib-2.0.so.0
libpthread.so.0
libdl.so.2
libutil.so.1
libm.so.6
libX11.so.6
libstdc++.so.6
libgcc_s.so.1
libc.so.6
libgio-2.0.so
libgio-2.0.so.0
module.so
```

[this also](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2524&start=0) suggests gtk.

Answer (score 16):

It might not be written in Python. The reason you see Python code is users can write scripts/plugin in Pythons to extend Sublime Text. I suspect it is written in C++ with GTK as GUI toolkit.